# Can't uninstall Python 2.7.16 on Mac

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, python-2.x

I am gonna newly install Python 3.8 after uninstalling the previous version - python 2.7.16

So I used these commands on terminal

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' 
cd /usr/local/bin/
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

But when I type "python --version" after finishing these commands, I can still see "Python 2.7.16".

I still remain it and type `sudo pip install django==3.0.1` to install django. But I can see this error

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/Users/milosavgluscevic/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/milosavgluscevic/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==3.0.1 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==3.0.1
```

Comment: What happens when you type `python3 --version`?

Comment: I can see "python 3.7.3"

Comment: But I can't do this "sudo pip install django==3.0.1"

Comment: Your question basically comes down to needing to use `pip3` instead of `pip`

Comment: You may want to try sudo python3 -m pip install django==3.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do not remove** python 2.7 from your Mac computer, python 2.7 **is needed** by Mac, and the files are protected to be sure they are not removed. Set up a virtual environment if you want to run another version of python. In fact, python 2.7 is still important as the **basis** for most Linux system such as Ubuntu including Mac, just remember that in case in the future you are using python in another OS, but in the future, python 2.7 may be removed as we are **migrating code to python 3.6** right now.

Comment: The system-bundled python cannot be removed (easily), but is version 2.7.10, so version 2.7.16 must have been user-installed.